# listview getChildAt() doesn't work for imageview?

Tags: android, listview

I want to use imageview like a radio button in custom listview so i used a for loop and `getChildAt(position)` but it doesn't work well when i scroll down it doesn't change imageview image src.

This is my code :

```
lvChooseReader.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long id) {
                            for (int i = 0; lvChooseReader.getLastVisiblePosition() - lvChooseReader.getFirstVisiblePosition() > i; i++) {

 View childView = lvChooseReader.getChildAt(i);
               ImageView myImage= (ImageView) childView.findViewById(R.id.ivTest);

                if (i == position) {
                   rr.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_mark_default));
                }else {
                    rr.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_mark_selected));
                }
            }
            lvChooseReader.invalidateViews();
       }
 });
```

or could any one give me a link to make radio button on item click not the radio button onclick...

Comment: i will post the solution after 8 hours because my reputation is only 8

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i solved my problem by using static values :

i add this static variable in the dialogfragment which contain my listview

```
static int selectedReaderId;
```

and for onItemClick in listview i add this :

```
ChooseReader reader = chooseReaderArrayList.get(position);
selectedReaderId=reader.getReaderID();
lvChooseReader.invalidateViews();
```

then in the custom adapter inside my getview i add this

```
final ChooseReader chooseReader = readers.get(position);
if (chooseReader.getReaderID()==ChooseReaderDialog.selectedReaderId){
holder.ivTest.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_mark_default));
}else {    holder.ivTest.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_mark_selected));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lvChooseReader.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long id) {
                            for (int i = lvChooseReader.getFirstVisiblePosition(); lvChooseReader.getLastVisiblePosition() > i; i++) {

 View childView = lvChooseReader.getChildAt(i);
               ImageView myImage= (ImageView) childView.findViewById(R.id.ivTest);

                if (i == position) {
                   rr.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_mark_default));
                }else {
                    rr.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_mark_selected));
                }
            }
            lvChooseReader.invalidateViews();
```

The deference is:

In this code the value of i will be between first visible item to last visible item and in your case value of i was between on and total visible items.

For example:

If item 2-3-4-5 are visible i should be 1-2-3-4(position of these items in listview).
and in your case it was 0-1-2-3

Comment: in this code the value of i will be between first visible item to last visible item and in your case value of i was between on and total visible items.

Comment: for example lets say item 2-3-4 are visible now you clicked on 2nd item and your for loop starts from i=0-1-2. You want the reference of the 2nd item but getChildAt(0) will give you first item instead of 2nd.

Comment: yes i understand i will post my answer after 7 hours because my reputation is low

Comment: i solved it in a different way so i will post it after stackoverflow allow me to do this

Comment: thanks
but i tried your solution but it doesn't solve it
when scroll down the problem happen again no changing in the imageview

Comment: for that you need to do it in adapter. Just keep a selected index in adapter and update it in onitemClick and in getView if position is current selected index then change image else not

Comment: i used a similar thing like this but a static variable